# How to analyze the long running select query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a select query that has a subquery (select),

```
SELECT 
    count(*) AS count_1
FROM (SELECT 
          test.pg_status AS test_pg_status, test.errorcode AS test_errorcode, test.errordetails AS 
          test_errordetails, test.warningcode AS test_warningcode 
       FROM test
       WHERE '304ab306-16fe-4d12-affd-82c79c3bea4a'::uuid = test.sn_uuid) AS anon_1
```

This query is taking around 6 minutes to execute from my django app (not always, randomly), but when I execute this query from my psql command prompt, it is getting completed in 0.3 second.

Could someone help me to analyze the problem?

Note: I have an index created on sn_uuid, size of the test table data is 4GB and index data size is 21GB

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) (no screen shots please) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: For one, you could ditch the derived table (sub-query) and use `select count(*) from test where ...` directly. Why select so many columns if you don't need them? That _might_ hinder the optimizer to use e.g. an Index Only Scan but only the execution plan can tell us.

Comment: Use auto_explain to capture the execution plan and the query run by the application.

Comment: Hi All, please ignore this question, The data which I collected is in milliseconds and I thought it was seconds.

Comment: :-|   It was so impressive